# How to split String but retain the delimiter while it is inside a bracket?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I have a string,

```
String str = "(A,B),C,D,(E,F,G)";
String[] parts = str.split(",");
```

I want to split by the comma, but I need the comma inside the bracket

```
parts[0] = "(A,B)";
parts[1] = "C";
parts[2] = "D";
parts[3] = "(E,F,G)";
```

Comment: will this string be only chars or will it contain numbers as well?

Comment: `str.split(",(?![^()]*\\))");`